# Calculate current (nearest) side of rotated cube

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, matrix

I would like to find the current side and update the `$currentFace` property in my Cube class, every time the cube is rotated.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joecritch/tZBDW/

As you can see, I am updating the `$currentFace` successfully when I directly go to a face, using the menu. However, I am using a different approach for keyboard controls (using a 3D Matrix so that the cube doesn't go onto an incorrect axis).

What's the best way to calculate this?

I have an event handler for `afterRotation`, so the calculation code can be placed in there.

```
__afterRotation: function(e) {
  // ...
  // Insert calculation code?
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the Dot Product on the face normals? If you used the camera's Look At vector and dot it with the face normal, it will be -1 if the face is 'facing' you.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like it would be mathematically correct but I don't think there's built-in support for cameras in 3D CSS. I may take a look at Three.js instead